# Reconstruct surface from 3D triangular meshes

Tags: mesh, 3d-reconstruction

I have a 3D model, which consists of the 3D triangular meshes. I want to partition the meshes into different groups. Each group represents a surface, such as a planar face, cylindrical surface. This is something like surface recognition/reconstruction.

The input is a set of 3D triangular meshes. The output is the mesh segmentations per surface.

Is there any library meets my requirement?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to go into lots of mesh processing, then the point cloud library is a good idea, but I'd also suggest CGAL: http://www.cgal.org for more algorithms and loads of structures aimed at meshes.

Lastly, the problem you describe is most easily solved on your own:

1. enumerate all vertices
2. enumerate all polygons
3. create an array of ints with the size of the number of vertices in your "big" mesh, initialize with 0.
4. create an array of ints with the size of the number of polygons in your "big" mesh, initialize with 0.
5. initialize a counter to 0
6. for each polygon in your mesh, look at its vertices and the value that each has in the array. 
   if the values for each vertex are zero, increase counter and assign to each of the values in the vertex array and polygon array correspondingly. 
   if not, relabel all vertices and polygons with a higher number to the smallest, non-zero number.

The relabeling can be done quickly with a look up table. 
This might save you lots of issues interfacing your code to some library you're not really interested in.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at the PCL library, it has all these features and much more: http://pointclouds.org/